# Get command history from remote user on Linux server

Tags: linux, shell, command, remote-server

I have a `Linux` server and many users can access this by `ssh`. I need to get all `history commands` from users:

```
 - Date: the time of execution
 - Pwd: executable directory
 - Remote host ip
 - User
 - Command
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a coding problem, you should ask at one of our sister site (https://unix.stackexchange.com/ maybe).

Answer (score 1):

It's too long to summarize here, but this blog post gives the code and description for setting up a system that logs everything that users do on a system:

[Howto – bash audit / command logger](http://www.pointsoftware.ch/en/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/)

I've been using this personally for years and have found it invaluable.

As you requested, it logs date, time, current directory, user, and command.  The IP address should be available in /var/log/auth.log

**Update**: Since writing the above, I put my 'fork' of this on GitLab: [bash_franzi](https://gitlab.com/bitinerant/bash_franzi#bash_franzi)